# java.lang.ClassCastException: x cannot be cast to x

Tags: java, jpa, entity, classcastexception

The following code worked once:

```
private Map<Integer, Parkhaus> getCarparksDC() {
    System.out.println("DatabaseConnection.getCarparksDC() start.");
    List<DbParkhaus> locationDbParkhausList;

    locationDbParkhausList = this.dbParkhausEjb.getAll();

    Map<Integer, Parkhaus> returnValue = new HashMap<Integer, Parkhaus>();
    for (DbParkhaus carpark : locationDbParkhausList) {
        Parkhaus toPut = new Parkhaus();

        toPut.setId(carpark.getIdparkhaus());
        toPut.setLocation(new LatLng(carpark.getLatitude(), carpark.getLongitude()));
        toPut.setName(carpark.getName());

        returnValue.put(toPut.getId(), toPut);
    }
    System.out.println("DatabaseConnection.getCarparksDC() end.");
    return returnValue;
}
```

But if I try to run it now I get the following Exception:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: reichling.parkhausserver.entity.DbParkhaus cannot be cast to reichling.parkhausserver.entity.DbParkhaus
```

The only thing I changed in the code are some System.out.println in another method, which should be called later.

Any ideas how to solve it?

```
//DbParkhausEjb.getAll()

public List<DbParkhaus> getAll(){
    List<DbParkhaus> results;
    if(em == null){
        System.out.println("Entitymanager not initialized.");
    }
    results = em.createNamedQuery("DbParkhaus.findAll")
            .getResultList();
    return results;
}
```

EDIT:
After restarting the server the code worked again until I changed something again. Seems like there is a problem with redeploying. I'm using netbeans and glassfish.

Comment: Are you running this code in a JEE environment? If so, is it possible that your code is crossing class loaders?

Comment: Yes netbeans with an integraded classfish server. Restarting the server seems to work. If redeploying after changes crosses class loaders that seems to be the problem.

Comment: There are a lot of quirks with containers and classloaders, especially when IDEs get involved. Would suggest you read about glassfish-specific configuration to make class loading deterministic. But if it works on restart, the issue is probably caused by hot deploys by the IDE, and that shouldn't be a problem in production (assuming you won't do hot deploys).